# Send a Message or Notification to the friend in facebook

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I need to send a message or a notification about an event or something else to my friend from my facebook application for website. The rest api is no longer in use ....So is there any other ways...Sample codes???

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't as yet send notifications via the new API.

> While we currently don't allow
>   applications to send messages through
>   this API, we're always thinking about
>   new functionality to offer through
>   Facebook Platform.

Source: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/291

Answer (score 1):

"Sample codes" and documentation, straight from the horse's mouth: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

See especially the sections labelled "Reading" and "Publishing"

Comment: (seriously, did you even *try* searching for it?)